# Creating a list of lists by multiplying a list unexpectedly leaves inner lists connected

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, copy

Let's say I want to create a list of lists to be filled later, that looks like that:

```
[['', ''], ['', ''], ['', '']]
```

I can create it like so:

```
rows=3
cols=2

A=['']*cols
B=[A[:]]*rows
```

However, the inner lists are the same object, as can be seen:

```
B[0][0]='!'
print (B)
```

Output:

```
[['!', ''], ['!', ''], ['!', '']]
```

This occurs even though I used `B=[A[:]]*rows` rather than `B=[A]*rows`; using  `B=[A][:]*rows` does not solve the problem.

If `A[:]` should efficiently create a full copy (rather than just a reference) by slicing A, then why does this occur?

P.S.

Obviously this can be easily solved for example by:

```
this_text=[]
temp=[]
for i in range(cols):
    A.append('')
for i in range(rows):
    B.append(A[:])
```

My aim is improved understanding, not creating this specific list of lists.

Comment: Because that how multiplication works.

Comment: Interesting.
So multiplying a non scalar will always clone only the reference to the object?
Is there a way to force it to truly copy the object instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
B=[A[:]]*rows
```

takes the **same** `list` instance `['' * cols]` **row** times.

Changing one reference to said instance will affect all references.

Use a comprehension instead to create independent lists.

```py
B=[A[:] for x in range(rows)]
```

Answer (score 3):

This will prevent `B` from being a list of copies, since it creates a new `A[:]` for each `x`:

```
B=[A[:] for x in range(rows)]
```